# Bash: syntax error in expression (error token is ...)

Tags: bash

This line in a bash file has been working for six months:

```
SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME="${SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME:scratch--folder}"
```

and today it decided to be no more, with this error:

```
SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME: scratch--folder: syntax error in expression (error token is "folder")
```

What does it mean?

For reference, here is the complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash

      SHIMMERCAT_SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME="${SHIMMERCAT_SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME:shimmercat-scratch--folder}"
REDIS_UNIX_SOCKET="/unpriv/$SHIMMERCAT_SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME/redis.sock"

if [[ -z ${DONT_RUN_REDIS+x} ]]; then 

    chown shimmercat:shimmercat $SHIMMERCAT_SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME

    ...
fi
```

Comment: Maybe try `chown shimmercat:shimmercat "$SHIMMERCAT_SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME"` (with the expansion in `""`)?  Which line is the error on?

Comment: The error is in line 3, the one that I wrote first in the question.

Comment: I can reproduce the error in both 3.2 and 4.4, when `SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME` is *set*. It's also possible that 4.0 introduced a bug that made it legal, and said bug wasn't fixed until 4.4; I don't have any older installations available to test that theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"${SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME:scratch--folder}"` is not a correct parameter expansion. Consider the following, where comma is the delimiter:

```
# Get string before first matching delimeter
${var%%,*}

# Get string before last matching delimeter
${var%,*}

# Get string after first matching delimeter
${var#*,}

# Get string after last matching delimeter
${var##*,}
```

As for how it worked I am not sure. *[Here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#overview) is a good reference for the different types of parameter expansions.*

Comment: Yepp, you are totally right. I should have added a "-", like: `SHIMMERCAT_SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME="${SHIMMERCAT_SCRATCH_FOLDER_NAME:-shimmercat-scratch--folder}"` . How it was working before, I have no idea :-(